# Display fixed size image in ImageView inside GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-gridview

I already know how to convert pixels into dpi. But I am still confused how to display a simple image in an `ImageView` inside a `GridView` for all screens(dpis).

For example let's take the below image:
[image]

The width/height is 220px/330px. My `GridView` is set as `android:numColumns="auto_fit"`. Now I have confusion with `android:columnWidth`. I set GridView columnswidth as 220px. It needs exactly the same size of the image width.
If I use px to dpi forumla then the Image in the `ImageView` is not displayed properly

Comment: what scaleType do you use for your ImageView?